# Datagridview Rows are showing Blur Data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

When I'm loading data to DataGridView it load all the data successfully but it show the rows data by blurring. When I click on row then row data display properly. In that case I have to click / select each DataGridViewRow to display the row data.

Cam somebody help with this issue?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with VB.NET.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to show your code. Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm certainly not in favour of images for no good reason but if this is a visual issue then a visual medium is required, i.e. show us a screen shot.

Comment: Make you app DPIAware: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103)

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have added2 images. First image is displayed when I open the windows form that contain datagridview. This datagrid view does not show the datagrid row. It show the picture of backgroundform or its parent form. Second Image is all about when I scroll down the datagridview data it start making it's text blurr. Thanks

Comment: @Jimi I have added 2 images. Can you please have a look and suggest me what to do. Is this any kind of setting or any code which I have to implement in my window app. The link you provided couldn't help me as I'm not much aware about the DPI etc. If this is any kind of code need to implement, please write.

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed the error in Flutter Using :

```
gridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.none,
headerGridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.none,
```

Inside of SfDataGrid Widget.

Here is my SfDataGrid Widget:

```
       SizedBox(
            width: constraint.maxWidth,
            height: constraint.maxHeight - 70,
            child: SfDataGridTheme(
              data: SfDataGridThemeData(
                  filterIconColor: Colors.pink,
                  filterIconHoverColor: Colors.purple,
                  sortOrderNumberBackgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                  sortOrderNumberColor: Colors.pink),
              child: SfDataGrid(
                selectionMode: SelectionMode.single,
                highlightRowOnHover: true,
                sortingGestureType: SortingGestureType.doubleTap,
                //These Two Entities Were The Reason Behind the Blurry Table: So always keep it NONE
                gridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.none,
                headerGridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.none,
                rowsCacheExtent: 200,
                key: taskController._taskTableGlobalKey,
                source: taskController._taskTableDataSource,
                columnWidthCalculationRange:
                    ColumnWidthCalculationRange.allRows,
                columnSizer: taskController._customColumnSizer,
                rowHeight: 55,
                rowsPerPage: taskController.rowsPerPage.value,
                allowFiltering: true,
                allowSorting: true,
                allowMultiColumnSorting: true,
                allowTriStateSorting: true,
                showSortNumbers: true,
                allowColumnsResizing: true,
                columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.auto,
                columns: <GridColumn>[
                  GridColumn(
                    minimumWidth: 150,
                    maximumWidth: 180,
                    columnName: AppStrings.taskTableTitle,
                    filterIconPadding:
                        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    filterPopupMenuOptions: const FilterPopupMenuOptions(
                      filterMode: FilterMode.checkboxFilter,
                      canShowSortingOptions: true,
                      canShowClearFilterOption: true,
                      showColumnName: false,
                    ),
                    label: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const Text(
                          AppStrings.taskTableTitle,
                          softWrap: true,
                        )),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem, you must always clean the grid before uploading new data

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = YourDataGridHere
dgv.Columns.Clear()
dgv.Rows.Clear()

'Now you can populate them with new data
'dgv.Columns.Add("col1", "col1")
'dgv.Columns.Add("col2", "col2")
'dgv.Columns.Add("col3", "col3")
'dgv.Rows.Add("pippo", "pluto", "paperino")
```

Comment: But this seems something different issue. As I'm filing data with table adapter that already handles clearing the datagrid view before filling?

Comment: I'm sinply loading a data into datagrid view with coding Me.tableBillTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database.TableBill)

Comment: When I fill the DataGridView it show its cells content little blur as shown in my second Image